# Percentage of Sum of two Pivot cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I'm trying to work out a small problem with my excel Pivot table. I have data from a Excel Sheet which i have made a Pivot table of. The data is structured as below

```
 Name | Count Cell1 | Sum of Cell 2 |
 Eric |      25      |      5        |
 Sam  |       5      |      1        | 
 Joe  |      10      |      5        |
```

What i want to have is a formula that takes the Count of Cell 1 and divide it by Sum of Cell 2 and display it in % like the example below.

```
 Name | Count Cell1 | Sum of Cell 2 | Difference|
 ------------------------------------------------
 Eric |      25      |      5        |     20%   |
 Sam  |       5      |      1        |     20%   |
 Joe  |      10      |      5        |     50%   |
```

All formulas i have tried only uses the original Table cells and not the sums of them.

So is there a smart way to have a formula lookup inside of a pivot table and display it in %?

Answer (score 2):

In your Pivot Table, you can enter a calculated field to do what you want.

1. Select somewhere in your pivot table (e.g. one of the Sum of Cell2 fields)
2. In the **PivotTable Tools** > **Options** ribbon, in the **Calculations** section, click **Fields, Items & Sets** and from there pick **Calculated Field**
3. Change the name to `Difference` and the Formula `=Cell2/Cell1`
4. In the **Field Settings** for that field, change the **Custom Name** to `Difference` and **Number Format** to `Percentage`

**EDIT - question updated for Count & Sum**
So, as far as I can see, trying to do the combination of Sum/Count really upsets it... the only workaround I could find was adding a helper column in the data source with just the number 1... in that way, the sum of that gives you the count, and so the Calculated Field can be `Cell2/HelperColumn` -horrible!

Comment: I'm sorry i made an mistake of writing my first entry which i corrected. The first Cell, Count all entries that the person has done, then the second displays how many of the Tasks the person done correctly. So First cell is a Count, second cell is a Sum.

By doing what you have said only takes the original value of the cell not the counted one so if a value has the value of 1111102 but it still counts as 1. Do I make myself clear enough of my issue?